# Запрос к API IBM Watson translate с помощью Boost::Asio

Tags: c++, curl, boost, asio, ibm

Имеется шаблон обращения к API переводчика IBM на curl

```
$ curl -X POST --user "apikey:{apikey}" \
--header "Content-Type: application/json" \
--data '{"text": ["Hello, world.", "How are you?"], "model_id":"en-es"}' \
"{url}/v3/translate?version=2018-05-01"
```

Пытаюсь сделать запрос в простом консольном приложении на Boost.Asio но не получаю ответа.
Url который выдается для доступа имеет вид: `https://api.au-syd.language-translator.watson.cloud.ibm.com/instances/5XXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXXX`
Не совсем понимаю как правильно оформить запрос.
При попытке привязки сокета на выданный url

`ip::tcp::resolver::query query("https://api.au-syd.language-translator.watson.cloud.ibm.com/instances/5XXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXXX", "443");`

Вызывается исключение, я так понимаю этот url надо как то использовать в запросе и пробовал разные варианты но безуспешно.
Строку с api:{key} преобразую в Base64

Весь код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/iterators/base64_from_binary.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/iterators/transform_width.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/iterators/insert_linebreaks.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/iterators/remove_whitespace.hpp>

#include <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>
#pragma comment(lib,"libcrypto.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "libeay32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "ssleay32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "libssl.lib")

using namespace boost::asio;
using namespace boost::archive::iterators;

int main()
{
    typedef insert_linebreaks<base64_from_binary<transform_width<std::string::const_iterator, 6, 8> >, 72 > it_base64_t;
    SSL_library_init();
    SSL_load_error_strings();
    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();

    //create socket
    io_service service;
    ssl::context ctx(ssl::context::method::sslv23_client);
    ssl::stream<ip::tcp::socket> sslSocket(service, ctx);
    ip::tcp::resolver resolver(service);
    auto it = resolver.resolve({ "api.au-syd.language-translator.watson.cloud.ibm.comt", "443" });
    boost::asio::connect(sslSocket.lowest_layer(), it);
    sslSocket.handshake(ssl::stream_base::handshake_type::client);


    //Encode key
    std::string s="apikey:W4XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    unsigned int writePaddChars = (3 - s.length() % 3) % 3;
    std::string base64(it_base64_t(s.begin()), it_base64_t(s.end()));
    base64.append(writePaddChars, '=');
    std::cout << "Base64 representation: " << base64 << std::endl;

    //format request
    boost::asio::streambuf request;
    std::ostream request_stream(&request);
    std::string data= "{'text': ['Hello, world.', 'How are you?'], 'model_id':'en-es'}\n";
    request_stream  << "POST /instances/56XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/v3/translate?version=2018-05-01 HTTP/1.1\n"
        <<"Host: api.au-syd.language-translator.watson.cloud.ibm.com\n"
        <<"Authorization: Basic "<<base64<<"\n"
        <<"User-Agent: curl/7.71.1\n"
        <<"Accept: */*\n"
        <<"Content-Type: application/json\n"
        <<"Content-Lenght: "<<data.size()<<"\n\n"
        << data;

    //send
    write(sslSocket,request);

    //recive
    size_t read = 0;
    const unsigned int MAX_BUF_LENGTH = 4096;
    std::vector<char> buff(MAX_BUF_LENGTH);
    std::string rcv;
    do
    {
        read = sslSocket.read_some(buffer(buff));       
        if (read == -1) {
            std::cout << "ERROR RECV\n";
        }
        else {
            rcv.append(buff.cbegin(), buff.cbegin() + read);
        }
    } while (read == MAX_BUF_LENGTH);
    std::cout << rcv << std::endl;
}
```

Исправил запрос, теперь идентичен тому что отправляет Curl. Без создания ssl соединение по прежнему сбрасывается. при попытке создать ssl сокет вызывается исключение:

> Вызвано исключение по адресу 0x0F93B144 (libssl-1_1.dll) в
> ConsoleApplication3.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при чтении
> по адресу 0x0000009C.

Comment: как минимум, здесь нет ни каких признаков установки ssl-соединения — само собой, автомагически это не происходит... также много ошибок в запросе (на беглый взгляд): в «аргументе» запроса должен быть «путь» на сервере, а не полный url, а имя хоста должно быть в поле `Host`.... Также в заголовке ответа нужно указывать `Content-Length` (или хотя бы выполнять `shutdown` пишущей части сокета после запроса). А ещё заголовок должен завершаться двумя концами строки `\r\n\r\n`... Что использовать для ssl/http/https вместо/вместе с `boost`'ом или какую его часть я советовать не возьмусь...

Comment: да и посмотреть, как должен выглядеть заголовок http-запроса можно добавив в команде `curl` выше ключик `-v` или `--trace-ascii -`

Comment: возможно для ваших целей больше подойдет https://cpp-netlib.org/0.9.2/? библиотека на основе boost. реализующая все прикладные сетевые протоколы типа http(s) и т.д.

Comment: @Fat-Zer использовать boost.beast

Comment: Да, там Asio + Beast намного лучше выглядит, не придётся руками всё прописывать.

Comment: вот тут про создание ssl-соединения через boost::asio - https://habr.com/ru/post/271203/

Comment: @AlexeyNikolaev, да вообще-то, там прям на офсайте Boost'а есть пример.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо всем за помощь. По итогу получилось сделать запрос с ssl и успешно получить ответ с использованием Boost.Beast

Вот код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/iterators/base64_from_binary.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/iterators/transform_width.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/iterators/insert_linebreaks.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/iterators/remove_whitespace.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/core.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/http.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/ssl.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/version.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/connect.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ssl/error.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ssl/stream.hpp>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

namespace beast = boost::beast; // from <boost/beast.hpp>
namespace http = beast::http;   // from <boost/beast/http.hpp>
namespace net = boost::asio;    // from <boost/asio.hpp>
namespace ssl = net::ssl;       // from <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>
using tcp = net::ip::tcp;       // from <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>

#pragma comment(lib, "libcrypto.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "libssl.lib")


int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    typedef boost::archive::iterators::insert_linebreaks<boost::archive::iterators::base64_from_binary<boost::archive::iterators::transform_width<std::string::const_iterator, 6, 8> >, 72 > it_base64_t;
    //Encode key
    std::string s = "apikey:WXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    unsigned int writePaddChars = (3 - s.length() % 3) % 3;
    std::string base64(it_base64_t(s.begin()), it_base64_t(s.end()));
    base64.append(writePaddChars, '=');
    std::cout << "Base64 representation: " << base64 << std::endl;

#pragma region beast
    try
    {
        // The io_context is required for all I/O
        net::io_context ioc;
        ssl::context ctx(ssl::context::sslv23_client);
        // This holds the root certificate used for verification
        ctx.load_verify_file("rootca.crt");
        // Verify the remote server's certificate
        ctx.set_verify_mode(ssl::verify_none);
        // These objects perform our I/O
        tcp::resolver resolver(ioc);
        beast::ssl_stream<beast::tcp_stream> stream(ioc, ctx);
        // Set SNI Hostname (many hosts need this to handshake successfully)
        if (!SSL_set_tlsext_host_name(stream.native_handle(),"api.au-syd.language-translator.watson.cloud.ibm.com"))
        {
            beast::error_code ec{ static_cast<int>(::ERR_get_error()), net::error::get_ssl_category() };
            throw beast::system_error{ ec };
        }
        // Look up the domain name
        auto const results = resolver.resolve("api.au-syd.language-translator.watson.cloud.ibm.com", "https");
        // Make the connection on the IP address we get from a lookup
        beast::get_lowest_layer(stream).connect(results);
        // Perform the SSL handshake
        stream.handshake(ssl::stream_base::client);
        //format POST request
        std::string data="{\"text\": [\"Hello, world.\", \"How are you?\"], \"model_id\":\"en-ru\"}";
        http::request<http::string_body> req;
        req.method(http::verb::post);
        req.target("/instances/56XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/v3/translate?version=2020-08-11");
        req.version(11);
        req.set(http::field::host, "api.au-syd.language-translator.watson.cloud.ibm.com");
        req.set(http::field::authorization, "Basic "+base64);
        req.set(http::field::user_agent, "curl/7.71.1");
        req.set(http::field::accept, "*/*");
        req.set(http::field::content_type, "application/json");
        req.set(http::field::content_length, data.size());
        req.body()=data;
        req.prepare_payload();
        // Send the HTTP request to the remote host
        http::write(stream, req);
        // This buffer is used for reading and must be persisted
        beast::flat_buffer buffer;
        // Declare a container to hold the response
        http::response<http::dynamic_body> res;
        // Receive the HTTP response
        http::read(stream, buffer, res);
        // Write the message to standard out
        std::cout << res << std::endl;
        // Gracefully close the stream
        beast::error_code ec;
        stream.shutdown(ec);
        if (ec == net::error::eof)
        {
            // Rationale:
            // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25587403/boost-asio-ssl-async-shutdown-always-finishes-with-an-error
            ec = {};
        }
        if (ec)
            throw beast::system_error{ ec };

        // If we get here then the connection is closed gracefully

    }
    catch (std::exception const& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
#pragma endregion beast
}
```